# Base R "type.convert()" of numeric NA returns logical

Tags: r, type-conversion

When I have a single numeric NA, it is incorrectly converted to a `logical`:

```
class(type.convert(NA_real_, as.is = TRUE))      
[1] "logical"
```

Does anyone know how to do this differently to get a correct result (@PGSA correctly pointed out that this functionality is by design for some reason)? The intended use is for nested lists, so a simple replacement will not work.

Compare for example the following:

```
lapply(
    type.convert(
        list(
            list(NA, 1), 
            list(NA_real_), 
            list("a", "b")
        ), 
        as.is = TRUE
    ), 
    function(x) lapply(
        x, 
        function(y) class(y)
    )
)
```

**EDIT:**
Trying out different proposed solutions:

The wrapper function `my_type_convert()` works fine but returns an "integer" instead of a "numeric" for `c(NA_real_, 1)`.

```
# Example data
dat <- list(
  list(c(NA_real_, 1)),
    NA_real_,
  list(NA_real_),
  list(NA_character_),
  list(NA_integer_),
  list(c("a", NA)),
  list(c(3L, 4L)),
  list(list(c(NA_real_, 1.3), c("a", NA)))
)

# Wrapper function (proposed by @PGSA and adapted to work with vectors of lenght > 1)
my_type_convert <- function(x, ...) {
  if (is.atomic(x)) {
    if (length(x) == 1L && is.na(x)) {
      x
    } else {
      type.convert(x, ...)
    }
  } else {
    lapply(x, function(x) my_type_convert(x, ...))
  }
}

res1 <- my_type_convert(
  x = dat,
  as.is = TRUE
)

# Setting argument `tryLogical = FALSE` as proposed by @jay.sf
res2 <-  type.convert(dat, as.is = TRUE, tryLogical = FALSE) 

# Checks for wrapper function
lapply(
  res1,
  function(x) {
    lapply(
      x,
      function(y) class(y)
    )
  }
)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "numeric"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "numeric"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "character"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "character"


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
[1] "list"

lapply(res1[[8]][[1]], function(x) class(x))
[[1]]
[1] "numeric"

[[2]]
[1] "character"

# Checks for argument `tryLogical = FALSE`
lapply(
  res2,
  function(x) {
    lapply(
      x,
      function(y) class(y)
    )
  }
)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "logical"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "logical"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "logical"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "logical"


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "character"


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
[1] "list"

lapply(res2[[8]][[1]], function(x) class(x))
[[1]]
[1] "numeric"

[[2]]
[1] "character"
```

Comment: When you say "how to get a correct result" what is your expectation - what would be correct for your use case?

Comment: The function description says "Convert a data object to logical, integer, numeric, complex, character or factor as appropriate." So if I explicitly set `NA_real_`, I would expect `type.convert(NA_real_)` to keep a numeric instead of converting it to a logical.

Comment: I think you may have to implement an element-wise `is.na()` check before type conversion, annoyingly.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation `?type.convert`:

> Vectors which are entirely missing values are converted to logical,
> since NA is primarily logical.  [...] vectors containing just F, T,
> FALSE, TRUE and values from na.strings are converted to logical.

This seems to be the intended behaviour.

Possible workaround:

```
# test data
test <- list(
  list(NA, 1), 
  list(NA_real_), 
  list("a", "b"))

# recursive helper function
tconv_omitNA <- function(x) {
  if (is.atomic(x)) {
    if (is.na(x)) {
      x 
      } else {
        type.convert(x, as.is = TRUE)
      }
  } else {
    lapply(x, tconv_omitNA)
  }
}

# test:
lapply(
  
  lapply(test, tconv_omitNA)
  , 
  function(x) lapply(
    x, 
    function(y) class(y)
  )
)

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "logical"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "integer"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "numeric"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "character"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that but hoped you could bypass that somehow by setting a option. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @moremo possible workaround added - would that get your desired output (note, may get slow with very deep nesting)

Comment: Thanks for the possible workaround. I've modified the check and posted it in the EDIT of the my question.

Answer (score 2):

We can set `tryLogical=FALSE`.

```
> type.convert(NA_real_, as.is=TRUE, tryLogical=FALSE) |> class()
[1] "integer"
```

Your example:

```
> lapply(
+   type.convert(
+     list(
+       list(NA, 1), 
+       list(NA_real_), 
+       list("a", "b")
+     ), 
+     as.is = TRUE,
+     tryLogical=FALSE
+   ), 
+   function(x) lapply(
+     x, 
+     function(y) class(y)
+   )
+ )
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "integer"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "integer"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "character"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "character"
```

Referring to your **edit**:

```
> type.convert(dat1, as.is=TRUE, tryLogical=FALSE) |> 
+   rapply(class, how='list')
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[2]]
[1] "integer"

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "character"


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
[1] "integer"


[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
[[8]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "numeric"

[[8]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "character"
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat1)
list(list(c(NA, 1)), NA_real_, list(NA_real_), list(NA_character_), 
    list(NA_integer_), list(c("a", NA)), list(3:4), list(list(
        c(NA, 1.3), c("a", NA))))
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason that works not in the recursive more realistic example given in my EDIT.

Comment: @moremo Apparently works fine for me also for your new example, see edit.

Comment: Yes, it works as you use specifically `lapply` to account for the structure of that object. But the beauty of `type.convert()` is that "the function is called recursively for each column or list element". And this does not work with the additional argument `tryLogical = FALSE` as expected (see my edit).

Comment: @moremo Thanks for pointing to the beauty, `lapply` actually is redundant. Still works, though, see edited edit.

Comment: Which R Version are you working on? On R 4.1.0 this is definitely not the case.

Comment: @moremo Good point, running R4.3.2. Couldn't hurt to update yours, it's almost three years old.